# Is there a way to move a stuck ragdoll/corpse (that can't be resurrected)?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

[image: Gunjar's naked (but not nude) corpse with head stuck in chair]
<sub>(Click/tap on the image above to view the higher-resolution, original image.)</sub>

This is Gunjar's corpse. I want to move it, but his head is stuck. I tried `moveto player`, but it didn't work. I tried resurrecting him before doing that, but he's stone-dead. `tcl` doesn't seem to do anything. Why I want to move his body is because I want to use it as a (temporary) storage container on the other side of the room.

Is there a way to separate him from the object or is chair-head his final form?

Comment: Is removing an option?

Comment: You mean deleting the corpse? I'll add my goal to the question.

Comment: Exactly. Would be the easiest thing to do I guess. But only if you don't want the corpse anymore ofc.

Comment: How about removing the chair?

Comment: I guess I'm OK with that.

Comment: What do you mean by "stone dead:?

Comment: I just mean he's dead, Jim.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do:

1. Open console by pressing the key to the left of 1. In my country it is ½, but other  layouts may be different.
2. Click on the chair with the mouse so its ID number is shown.
3. type "disable" without the quotation marks and hit enter.
4. Close console.
5. Move him.
6. Open console again. the ID for the chair should still be shown.
7. Type "enable" without the marks and hit enter.
8. Close console.

If all else fails, use the above procedure to disable the corpse instead. At least he is out of the way then. :-)

A better option for temporary storage: When you have killed the two Imperials, run down the way they came from, turn left, and store your stuff in one of the two chests in that room.

Answer (score 0):

How about shooting an exploding Dwarven bolt at the chair?   Perhaps it will just bounce away?

Comment: With over 200 hrs in the game, I can safely say that's quite unlikely. Objects that are more for visual decoration, some for interaction(like chairs), are never affected by spells, shouts or physical touch with weapons for example. Unless there is a mod for it, of course.

Comment: His head is stuck in the chair, causing him to not move away.